# C# LINQ to Entity .Count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to the Entity Framework. I am attempting to get a count from a LINQ query that should return 1 result. The count is always 0 though. I know that the data is there and the relationship is sound in the edmx.

Here is the code:

```
LineItem li = order.LineItems.Where(i => i.ID == lineItemId).FirstOrDefault();
if (li != null)
{
    if (li.Notes.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get note data
    }
}
```

Now ListItem is not null so I am able to get to the count call. Again I have verified that I have my data as my debugging nets the .Where match as "52635 == 52635"

Is there something I am missing here in order to get my count? Or is there any suggestion to how I can debug this problem further?

I am using Entity Framework 4 +

Thanks!

Comment: Have you stepped into a debugger and examined li.Notes at the point where you're calling Count on it? I suspect the issue is there, and not with the count property.

Comment: Show the code that retrieves `order`, the problem is probably there (as alluded to by @DanielAWhite's answer).

Comment: Do I need a .Include if I am able to get to my Notes through the Navigation Property? The relationship is there and I get an error when I try to use the .Include.

Comment: Notes are not loaded unless u specify it.
be sure about the entity name: is it 'Notes' or 'LineItemNotes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is an issue with the record in the DB being deleted. Sorry guys! Thanks for the help though!!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `Include` notes.

Comment: Thanks. When I try that:
LineItem li = order.LineItems.Include("LineItemNotes").Where(i => i.ID == lineItemId).FirstOrDefault(); I get: CS0122: 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Include(bool, bool)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 1):

+1 on Include notes.  When you've done that you should use the more efficient `if(li.Notes.Any())` in place of `if(li.Notes.Count() > 0)`.

Also, you may find that using `li.Notes.Count` which is a property on the collection type used by Notes won't work in the same way as `li.Notes.Count()` which is a Linq extension method.  I'm not convinced without checking that you need Include.